# Модификаторы функции scanf()

Tags: c, функции, scanf

интересует принципы работы модификаторов функции `scanf()` в C.
Знаю, что например при помощи записи такого вида `scanf("%[<]", &symbol)` могу задать конкретный символ который нужно прочитать.
А так же с помощью такой записи `scanf("%*c")` могу отбросить символ и не выделять под него переменную. 
Корректна ли будет запись такого вида `scanf(" %*[<] %lli %*[;] %lli %*[>]", &numMIN, &numMAX)`?

Нужно считать два значения, которые являются диапазоном интервала. Вводные данные имеют вид `<10;20>`, `<    45   ;  56  >` или 
`<
23
;
34
>`
 пробелы, табуляция и т.д. значения не имеют, а вот корректность и последовательность символов имеет.

Пробовал оформить это все вот так,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int numMIN, numMAX;
    char a;
    if (((scanf("%*[<]")) == 1) && ((scanf("%lli", &numMIN)) == 1))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

но возвращает 1.

Существует ли возможность оформить условие так, чтобы можно было пропустить конкретный символ, при этом не создавая под него отдельную переменную и иметь возможность проверить является ли вводимых символ корректным?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- > Знаю, что например при помощи записи такого вида `scanf("%[<]", &symbol)` могу задать конкретный символ который нужно прочитать.

  Формат `%[]` читает не символ, а *строку* из указанных символов и требует аргумента типа `char *`, указывающего на начало массива `char`.

  (Такой указатель практически никогда не приходится получать при помощи `&`. Применение `&` с форматами `%s` и `%[]` - обычно ошибка.)
- > Корректна ли будет запись такого вида `scanf(" %*[<] %lli %*[;] %lli %*[>]", &numMIN, &numMAX)`?

  Корректна, но такая запись будет принимать и вход вида `<<<<123 ;;;;;4>>`. В этом заключался ваше замысел? Подозреваю, что нет.

  Если вы хотели просто потребовать наличия в входе по одному разделителю `<`, `;` и `>` (возможно с пробелами), то вам не нужно было привлекать формат `%[]`. Это требование реализуется просто прямым указанием требуемого символа в строке формата `scanf`

  ```
  scanf(" < %lli ; %lli >", &numMIN, &numMAX)
  ```

  Никаких переменных при этом заводить не надо.
- > `if (((scanf("%*[<]")) == 1) ...`

  Это заведомо неработоспособно. Подавленные при помощи `*` присваивания не включаются в финальный счетчик, возвращаемый `scanf`.